# how can i get repository of many entities in one getRepository

Tags: symfony, repository, entity

I have tried this but it wont work it just execute the first entity

```
$resultat = $con->getRepository("PFESiivtBundle:Categorie","PFESiivtBundle:Evenement",
"PFESiivtBundle:Projet")->findBy(array('idPublication' =>$respub),array('id'=>'DESC') );
```

Comment: You can't, you should use join close between your entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not going to work, you should create a `Repository` and then Join your Tables,

```
class CategorieRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function getCategorieRelatedDataByIdAndIdPublication($idPublication)
   {
       $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
       $qb->select('c', 'e', 'p')
        ->from('PFESiivtBundle:Categorie', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.eveniment', 'e')
        ->leftJoin('c.project', 'p')
        ->where('c.id = :id')
        ->andWhere('c.idPublication = :id_publication')
        ->setParameter('id_publication', $idPublication)

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
   }
}
```

The join will depend on your mapping, without mapping structure I cant give you proper code.

Then in `Controller` you will use as follow:

`$resultat = $con->getRepository("PFESiivtBundle:Categorie")-> getCategorieRelatedDataByIdAndIdPublication($idPublication);`